# Android app to disable the power button

Tags: android

I'm looking for an Android app that will completely disable the power button or make it much more difficult to accidentally press it (require long-press, double-press, etc.).

A root app is fine.

Gratis or paid, but prefer gratis.

Open-source or closed-source, but prefer open-source (not a requirement).

Comment: Not tested, but take a look at [Xposed additions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) and [Button Remapper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464). Both need root, and the first obviously also the Xposed framework. For more, check [here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_546) ;)

Comment: [This](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-remap-the-hardware-buttons-on-your-android-phone-1443192245) might be worth taking a look at. I didn't test it though.